Cross-Referencing by Name
Is there a package that provides the following functionality:
\begin{definition}[foo-bar]\label{def:foo_bar}
...
\end{definition}

We can use a \xref{foo-bar} to do ...

Which should produce identical output as using \hyperref[def:foo_bar]{foo-bar}. I dislike the verbosity of the latter.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Sounds like a job for \nameref:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}[foo-bar]\label{def:foo_bar}
...
\end{definition}

We can use a \nameref{def:foo_bar} to do ...

\end{document}

